# How do I share a question or answer from the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, sharing

I could not find any button or menu option to share a question or an answer from the Android app version of Stack Exchange.

Does anyone know if such feature exists?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230434/sharing-question-from-mobile-app-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Version 1.0.47 of the app and I can share questions/answers by tapping on the three dots to the right of the posted date.

[image]

will bring up this menu

[image]

Comment: All I can focus on, in your picture, is that your battery is low *and it's not on charge* @_@ (and, as ever, Randall Munroe [got there first](http://m.xkcd.com/1373/))