# Is it possible to add a question to favorites using the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I have been using the Android app for Stack Exchange since it was released.

But I'm missing one feature of the web-page: when I browse through the questions, I'd like to be able to add them to my favorites while using the app. But I haven't found how to do it without a browser. (At the moment I don't know if this is a limitation of the API or of the app.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can:

[image]

[image]

The pictures are from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268996/3187556