# Able to add favorite question but unable to find the already added favorites

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I am using android app for the stack Exchange.I am able to mark a question as favorite but  I am not able to find a way to see my favorite questions in the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add a question to favorites using the StackExchange Android app?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275099/is-it-possible-to-add-a-question-to-favorites-using-the-stackexchange-android-ap)

Comment: I am able to add the question to favorite but I am not able to see the questions which are added to favorites.

Comment: @Laurel Not only is that dupe not asking the same question, it's also out of date and wrong now :)

Comment: @Laurel http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275099/is-it-possible-to-add-a-question-to-favorites-using-the-stackexchange-android-ap?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment315358_275101

Comment: Previous question was how to add in browser, my question is how to see the fav in Android app which was not answered there

Comment: There is a duplicate on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229658/favorite-questions-in-the-android-app/229697#229697

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to view a list of your favorite questions within the Android app, it's just  really clunky: you need to search for `infavorites:mine` in the Android app, which will bring up a list of your favorite questions.

See [Favorite questions in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229658/favorite-questions-in-the-android-app/) on MSE for more details. A feature to make this easier to use is apparently being worked on.